# What is the order of hooks in React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**React 18** implements a new hook: `useInsertionEffect`.

So with `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`, what is the order of these 3 hooks at component generation ?

Answer (score 12):

According to the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#library-hooks):

### useInsertionEffect

It fires synchronously **before** all DOM mutations. Use this to inject styles into the DOM **before** reading layout in `useLayoutEffect`. So it runs before `useLayoutEffect`.

### useLayoutEffect

It fires synchronously **after** all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render.

### useEffect

It will run after the render is committed to the screen. So it runs after `useLayoutEffect`.

Therefore the order of running is:

1. useInsertionEffect
2. useLayoutEffect
3. useEffect

Answer (score 0):

According to the [new React Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useInsertionEffect#caveats), i think maybe a little mistake has been made in the old document, because the new document says the execution timing of useInsertionEffect is not guaranteed, it may run either before or after the DOM has been updated. however, the order of these three hooks is totally right